# Cast to nullable list of double gives an error

Tags: c#

In my database I have DOUBLE PRECESION type(Postgressql)
in my query the field which is double precision could be null ,so I have made this list nullable  but during the casting I get

> "Specified cast is not valid"

List is defined like this:

```
public List<double?> abb_conv { get; set; }
```

I got error in this line:

```
  _powerConv.abb_conv.Add((double?)dt["abb_conv"]);
```

where `dt` is the name of `Datatable`

Comment: What is type of `dt`?

Comment: @Fabio datatable

Comment: What is the actual type of the value inside `dt["abb_conv"]`? What does `dt["abb_conv"]?.GetType()?.FullName ?? "null"` say?

Comment: Also, `dt` cannot be `DataTable` since `DataTable` does not declare a `[x]` indexer property.

Comment: You may need to check for `DBNull`

Comment: try Convert.ToDouble(dt[column])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `dt` be the data table and you want to get the value of the column `abb_conv`, try the following:

```
 int rowNumber = 0;
 _powerConv.abb_conv.Add(dt.Rows[rowNumber].Field<double?>("abb_conv"));
```

Please note:

> The code you are using(`dt["abb_conv"]`) won't compile if `dt` is a
>   Datatable, since `Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'DataTable'`

Answer (score 1):

You can read value from the `DataRow`

For DataTable it will look like this:

```
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    var value = row.Field<double?>("abb_conv");
    list.Add(value);
}
```

But of course underlying value should be correspondent `double` type.

For whole list

```
List = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<double?>("abb_conv").ToList();
```